# Why am I getting a "More than one row returned" error inside this postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a game table and a child gameeffect table.  I'm trying to create a function that will find all games for which the most recent gameeffect row has a created_at date older than a certain number of minutes (passed in as a parameter).  Here's the code:

```
create or replace function end_idle_games(idle_time int)
returns table(game_id integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin

    create temp table temp_game_ids(game_id int);

    with open_game_effects as ( -- gets all the game effects for any open games
        select ge.*
        from gameeffect ge
        join game g on g.game_id = ge.game_id
        join gamestatus gs on gs.game_status_id = g.game_status_id
        where gs.game_status = 'open'
    ),
    latest_game_effects as ( -- gets the latest game effect for each game and calculates the time since it was created in minutes
        select oge.*, extract(epoch from (now() at time zone 'utc' - oge.created_at))/60 as idle_minutes
        from open_game_effects oge
        where oge.game_effect_id = (select max(oge1.game_effect_id) from open_game_effects oge1 group by oge1.game_id)
    ),
    idle_games as ( -- gets all game ids with an idle minutes greater than the passed in idle time
        select lge.game_id
        from latest_game_effects lge
        where lge.idle_minutes > idle_time
    )

    insert into temp_game_ids (game_id) select i.game_id from idle_games i;
    
    return query
        select t.game_id from temp_game_ids t;

end;
$$;
```

When I call the function e.g. `select * from end_idle_games(120);` I'm getting a **more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression** error.  I know that the line it's complaining about is:

`insert into temp_game_ids (game_id) select i.game_id from idle_games i`

because when I replace it with:

`insert into temp_game_ids (game_id) select 99`

the function works.  What I don't understand is why it's throwing the error?

Comment: You don't need the INSERT anyway. It's a waste of resources. Just return the result of your query directly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried that originally: return query select i.game_id from idle_games i.  Postgres complained that the return statement couldn't 'see' the idle_games CTE.

Comment: I'm going to say it is this: `oge.game_effect_id = (select max(oge1.game_effect_id) from open_game_effects oge1 group by oge1.game_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid error on my part. The error was actually occurring on this line:
`where oge.game_effect_id = (select max(oge1.game_effect_id) from open_game_effects oge1 group by oge1.game_id)` because the subquery *does* return multiple rows.  I should have been using the 'in' operator instead of '='.  Also, @a_horse_with_no_name helped me to see that I could ditch the temp table by wrapping the entire expression in the return statement like so:

```
create or replace function end_idle_games(idle_time int)
returns table(game_id integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query
        with open_game_effects as ( -- gets all the game effects for any open games
            select ge.*
            from gameeffect ge
            join game g on g.game_id = ge.game_id
            join gamestatus gs on gs.game_status_id = g.game_status_id
            where gs.game_status = 'open'
        ),
        latest_game_effects as ( -- gets the latest game effect for each game and calculates the time since it was created in minutes
            select oge.*, extract(epoch from (now() at time zone 'utc' - oge.created_at))/60 as idle_minutes
            from open_game_effects oge
            where oge.game_effect_id in (select max(oge1.game_effect_id) from open_game_effects oge1 group by oge1.game_id)
        ),
        idle_games as ( -- gets all game ids with an idle minutes greater than the passed in idle time
            select lge.game_id
            from latest_game_effects lge
            where lge.idle_minutes > idle_time
        )
    
        select i.game_id from idle_games i;

end;
$$;
```

Comment: This way, you might even switch from `language plpgsql` to just `language sql`